# Counting duplicate entries in database

Tags: arrays, count, duplicates, duplicate-data, zipcode

I want to count the number of times that a zip code is entered into a database. I'm not sure if I am using the right function or not. Also eventually I need to separate the zip codes by the year they were entered int the data base. I know how to separate the years. What I really need help on is counting duplicate entries.
Here is my code.

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM zip ORDER BY time_register'; 
$result = mysql_query($sql,$db) or die(mysql_error(). "<br />SQL: $sql");
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);

do{
    $visitor_zip= array();
    $register = $row['time_register'];
    $register_year = date(Y,$register);

    print_r(array_count_values($visitor_zip));

} while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
```

---

**Answer**: Here is my code that works.

```
$sql = "SELECT `visitor_zip` AS `zip`, COUNT(`visitor_zip`) AS `cnt`
        FROM `zip`
        GROUP BY `visitor_zip`
        ORDER BY visitor_zip";

$result = mysql_query($sql,$db) or die(mysql_error(). "<br />SQL: $sql");

print '<table class="zip"><tr><td><b>Zip</b></td><td># of</td></tr>';
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    print '<tr><td>' . $row['zip'] .'</td><td>'.  $row['cnt'] . '</td></tr>';
}
print '</table>';
```

Comment: What are the fields in your table?

Comment: zip_id
visitor_zip 
visitor_id 
visitor_email
time_register
I am only using the  time_register(this is a time stamp) and visitor_zip at this time. 
I appreciate all the help that I have gotten already. I was completely on the wrong track trying to solve this problem. I was trying to find a php function to do this instead of changing the query to the database. Now I don't know how the write the code to display the information from the data base. Does this make sence.

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS cnt, zipcode FROM zip
GROUP BY zipcode
ORDER BY time_register
```

Comment: You probably want to add a min(time_register) in there somewhere, assuming that the FIRST entered date for each zip code is the one of interest.

Comment: I appreciate all the help that I have gotten already. I was completely on the wrong track trying to solve this problem. I was trying to find a php function to do this instead of changing the query to the database. Now I don't know how the write the code to display the information from the data base. Can you help!?

Comment: I haven't touched php in 5 years so I'm probably not the one to ask.  You might want to add this to your original question.

Answer (score 0):

```
select count(ZIPCODEFIELD) as cnt, ZIPCODEFIELD, time_register FROM zip
GROUP BY zipcode,time_register
```